# Can a unit in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, where $p$ is a prime, be negative?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is prime and that $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Is $-\alpha$ also a unit?

I tested a few examples in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{11}$ and was not able to get that $-\alpha$ is a unit. Are there any cases where this is true?

Comment: $-1$ is a unit no matter what ring you are in.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you talking about integers modulo a prime?  Aren't all of them (except those divisible by the prime) invertible?  Or are you talking about something else, e.g., $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Integers modulo a prime

Comment: $\alpha$ is a unit means there is a $\beta$ such that $\alpha\beta=1=\beta\alpha$. Then what is $(-\alpha)(-\beta)$?

Comment: Well, $4$ is a unit, but this is $-7$.

Comment: You should not think of $-x$ as a "negative" element in $\mathbf Z/p$ because this is not an ordered field (i.e. it admits no order relation compatible with + and $\times$), simply because$ -1$ can be a square mod $p$. Actually, $-x = (-1)x$, and $-1$ is always a unit.

Comment: What if $\alpha$ is a generator in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, then can $-\alpha$ also be a generator? Are generators and units different things?